# How to pass an array value from a method to another method in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to pass the value of an array from one method to another method in Laravel. Basically I have a method called **orderingSubmission** that recieves an array from an Ajax POST execution (that part works fine), but then I'm trying to pass the array values to another method called **orderingSubmissionReceipt** so I can finally render the view on order-summary page. I'm using sessions but they don't seem to work. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing please?

**Here's my route.php**

```
Route::get('/', function() { return redirect('home'); });
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@home');
Route::post('home', 'HomeController@activateCustomer');
Route::post('order-summary', 'HomeController@OrderingSubmission');
Route::get('order-summary', 'HomeController@orderingSubmissionReceipt');
```

**HomeController.php**

```
public function orderingSubmission(Request $request)
{
    $allValues2 = $request->get('users'); // This code works fine. It gets the array
    Log::info('This is orderingSubmission.....: ' . print_r($allValues2, true));

   Session::set('allValues2',$allValues2);

}

public function orderingSubmissionReceipt()
{
    $allValues3 = Session::get('allValues2'); // This code is not getting the session value
    Log::info('This is orderingSubmissionReceipt.....: ' . print_r($allValues3, true));

    return view('order-summary', [
        'people' => $allValues3
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create class variables, like this:

```
class A
{
private $allValues2 = array();

    function orderingSubmission(Request $request)
    {
        $this->allValues2 = $request->get('users');

        //the rest of the code in this method..
    }

    function orderingSubmissionReceipt()
    {
        //if you want to make a local variable first, you can do it like this:
        $allValues3 = $this->allValues2;
        Log::info('This is orderingSubmissionReceipt.....: ' . print_r($allValues3, true));

        //or, you can just use the variable directly, like this:
        Log::info('This is orderingSubmissionReceipt.....: ' . print_r($this->allValues2, true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use **$request->session->put()** and **$request->session->get()** as follows : Do not forget to add **Request $request in orderingSubmissionReceipt** function declaration.

```
public function orderingSubmission(Request $request)
{
    $allValues2 = $request->get('users'); // This code works fine. It gets the array
    Log::info('This is orderingSubmission.....: ' . print_r($allValues2, true));
    $request->session()->put('allValues2',$allValues2);

}

public function orderingSubmissionReceipt(Request $request)
{

    $allValues3 = $request->session()->get('allValues2'); // This code is not getting the session value
    Log::info('This is orderingSubmissionReceipt.....: ' . print_r($allValues3, true));

    return view('order-summary', [
        'people' => $allValues3
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `session()` helper method in case `Session` is not working or showing any error.

```
public function orderingSubmission(Request $request)
{
    $allValues2 = $request->get('users');
    session()->set('allValues2', $allValues2);
    Log::info('Value set to session: ' . session()->get('allValues2')); 
}

public function orderingSubmissionReceipt()
{
    Log::info('Value get from session: ' . session()->get('allValues2'));     
    $allValues3 = session()->get('allValues2');

    return view('order-summary', [
        'people' => $allValues3
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should do something like that:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request; //You probably already have that!

public function orderingSubmission(Request $request)
{
    $allValues2 = $request->get('users');
    $request->session()->put('allValues2', $allValues2);
    Log::info('Value set to session: ' . $request->session()->get('allValues2'));
}

public function orderingSubmissionReceipt(Request $request)
{
    Log::info('Value get from session: ' . $request->session()->get('allValues2'));
    $allValues3 = $request->session()->get('allValues2');

    return view('order-summary', [
        'people' => $allValues3
    ]);
}
```

For more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session

Comment: the results are the same.

Comment: or maybe I'm doing it wrong. How would you use $request->session()  in my code?

Comment: Just edited the answer. Check if that will work! I've tried it with simple variables and works well for me. If that doesn't work, try to encode the array as a json before put it in an array.